# Python, line iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, line

I am processing a file line by line

```
for line in mix_files[i]:
    if my_string in line:
       use the next line # How to get the next line
```

After a line containing the text is found, I need to work with the next line. Is there any easy way how to get the next line (e.g., increment an iterator), instead of the less confortable method:

```
get line number -> increment line number -> use the next line
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the iterator:

```
next_line = next(mix_files[i])
```

Note that this can raise `StopIteration` if the file has no more lines. You can tell `next()` to return a default value instead:

```
next_line = next(mix_files[i], None)
```

which will be returned instead of raising the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Martijn's response is good, but you could also use enumerate:

```
for j, line in enumerate(mix_files[i]):
    if my_string in line:
        try:
            next_line = mix_files[i][j+1]
        except IndexError:
            handle_end_of_file()
        else:
            do_whatever_with_next_line()
```

Comment: Only if `mix_files[i]` is a sequence; if it is a file object this won't work.